# Binding button in uniformgrid by index

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an `position` as `Int32[2]` which represents a certain position on a grid, so the x coordinate is `position[0]` and the y coordinate is `position[1]`. I also have a `UniformGrid`, see below. The position can change, and I want to have the button on the grid, which has the coordinates stored in position, to be green. So if position has the coordinates `[0,0]`, the upper left button on the grid should be green. If the position moves to `[0,1]`, the greenbackround should move there and `[0,0]` on the grid should be back to being white. How can I bind this?

The grid in XAML looks like this, where certain background colors are already set (the green moving figure cannot step on non-white fields):

```
        <ItemsControl Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding Size}" Columns="{Binding Size}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Focusable="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Width="30" Height="25" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="k">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" /> 
                                </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="f">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="g">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text}" Value="w">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have your `Fields` collection defined similar to something like this:

```
ObservableCollection<Field> Fields { get; set; }
```

with class:

```
 public class Field
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        ....
        public bool IsGreen{get;set;}//add with PropertyChanged event
    }
```

Then you only need to add another datatrigger as last:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsGreen}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</DataTrigger>
```

and set appropriate `Field's` flag when position changes e.g: `GetField(x,y).IsGreen= true`